# Writing to Pins using EFI_PCI_IO_PROTOCOL

Tags: boot, uefi, pci, edk2

I am trying to write a UEFI application to write to a device through EFI_PCI_IO_PROTOCOL. To do this I am calling Io.Write and Io.Read but I cannot seem to find the Offset/"Bar relative base address".

```
Data = 1;    
Status = PciIo->Io.Write(
                PciIo,                        //< this
                EfiPciIoWidthUint8,           //< width
                EFI_PCI_IO_PASS_THROUGH_BAR,  //< BarIndex
                offSet,                       //< Offset
                1,                            //< Count
                &Data);                       // Buffer
```

Is there any way to find the Offset of the pins or would I just have to guess and check?

I cannot find an example of what I'm trying to do so I am not 100% sure that this is the correct procedure. If there is a better way of writing to pins through a UEFI application I am open to suggestions.

Comment: You have to have documentation for the device. Every type of PCI device is different.

Comment: @prl If I cannot find documentation descriptive enough for my platform is there a way to find it? Or maybe common bar addresses to try?

Comment: what do you mean by find the Offset of the pins?

Comment: @zerocool If I'm not mistaken, I need the pci bar index and offset to access pins through EFI_PCI_IO_PROTOCOL.

Comment: in that case, you are the one configuring the bar and they are at a fixed offset from the start of the header the first bar is at 0x10 from the start of the header, so you have just to read where config space for that device is and add 0x10 to it, and  that is the first bar @silkyskate